# Passing EventHandler between several classes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a gui widget a dll library, a class that derives from a FORM (I thought about usercontrol but it doesn't have built in properties like Opacity and some more that i need).

Because I don't want to expose to the user of this control all the standard methods and propertis that this derived class will inherit, I've created a nothe class "middle-man"  that should encapsulate and expose only the needed methos to the user of this dll.
The problem is exposing the events.

This is an abstract example:

```
 class Class1
    {
        Class2 theClass2;
        public Class1()
        {
            theClass2 = new Class2();
            theClass2. += new EventHandler(theClass3_EventHandler);
            theClass2.TriggerEvent();
        }

        void theClass3_EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }

    class Class2
    {
        Class3 theClass3;


        public Class2()
        {
            theClass3 = new Class3();

        }

        public void TriggerEvent()
        {
            theClass3.Trigger();
        }


        class Class3
        {
            public event EventHandler theEvent;

            public void Trigger()
            {
                if (this.theEvent != null)
                    theEvent(this, new EventArgs());
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your question is. You want Class1 to encapsulate Class2 which encapsulates Class3? I don't get the use case.

Comment: i want class1 to handle the event that triggered in class3

Comment: when you say "handle" do you mean fire the event or just allow access to for subscribing to the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public event EventHandler theEvent {
    add {
      SomeNestedClass.theEvent += value;
    }
    remove {
      SomeNestedClass.theEvent -= value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inheritance is a is-a relationship. That means that everything that a Form can do should all sub classes be able to do. Since this is not the case for you, you should not derive the form.

As for the events. You need to redefine them in your "middle-man" class. And in that class simply subscribe on the events from the form and trigger them in the handler methods.

```
public class MyCoolControl : Control
{
    private Form _customForm;

    public MyCoonControl()
    {
       _customForm.Clicked += (source, e) => Clicked(source,e);
    }

    public event EventHandler Clicked = delegate {};
}
```

Comment: but in this case, MyCoolControl will still expose all built in properties and methods of the "control"

Comment: Well, yes. Everything added to a winform need to implement `Control`. Anything else is just a "hack".

Comment: I just want to expose limited number of methods and properties when user creates and instance my control.

Comment: then you need to create a complete fascade reimplementing all events as I showed in my example. But I strongly discourage you from doing so. `Control` is the base class for a reason.

Comment: But even if use Control,it also has a bunch of properties and methods. And control doesn't have Opacity property that form has...

Comment: @Mark.A - You can always add it to your custom control.  It sounds like your not willing to accept advice at this stage.

Comment: @Ramhound, but instance of a control also has bunch of methods! I want to expose just my methods.